# Dubious passage in Archimedes

Tags: greek, mathematics

I have been interested in finding and understanding the original Greek text for the following quote by Archimedes, which made it to Wikiquote:

**Those who claim to discover everything but produce no proofs of the same may be confuted as having actually pretended to discover the impossible.**

This is found in his treatise *On Spirals* (Περὶ ἑλίκων), a few sentences into the dedication to Dositheus. I have consulted two editions, but it's hard to read the old-style writing, so please excuse any possible mistakes. The Greek-only Herwagen (1544) seems to give the following:

[image]

> **1** οἱ φάμενοι μὲν πάντα εὑρίσκειν, ἀπόδειξιν δὲ αὐτῶν οὐδεμίαν ἐκφέροντες ἐλέγχωνται, ἀπό θ’ ὁμολογηκότες εὑρίσκειν τὰ ἀδύνατα.

The Greek-Latin edition by Rivault (1615) instead has:

[image]

> **2** οἱ φάμενοι μὲν πάντα εὑρίσκειν, ἀπόδειξιν δὲ αὐτῶν οὐδὲ μίαν ἐκφέροντες ἐλέγχωνται, ἁ [?!] ποθ’ ὁμολογηκότες εὐρίσκειν τὰ ἀδύνατα.

which was translated, a bit freely, to

> **2'** Qui praedicant omnia se invenire, demonstrationem vero eorum nullam proferentes, sophistice agunt, ea aliquando spondere videantur reperiisse, quae sunt impossibilia.

Rivault does specify, in a scholium a few lines before, that the source is damaged (*locus hic totus luxatus est*), so the small but relevant divergence of these two editions could have some explanation. Apart from that, the syntax of both readings makes no sense to me: ἀπό what, in Herwagen? and what is that ἁ supposed to mean in Rivault? What is going on here?

Comment: Have a look at Heiberg's critical edition p. 4 (with critical apparatus) and his Latin translation on the following page. http://www.wilbourhall.org/pdfs/Archimedes_VOL_II.pdf

Comment: Support the proposal for creating a Greek language stackexchange, now in the commitment phase: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Comment: @fdb Thank you for the link, I will look into it when I have better connection.

Comment: Thanks! I always wondered why there wasn't already one, or why they hadn't changed this one's name to "Ancient Language" or something.